# C# UTF-8 string not wanting to convert to ASCII (or something readable anyways)

Tags: c#, .net, encoding, utf-8, ascii

I'm trying to convert a string which is being read from a file. I do not know how the file was made or created (encoding-wise) but here's the deal: I'm getting this string:

"operaci�n" which should come up as "operación" (operation in Spanish).

I've tried changing encodings when reading the file:

```
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("file.txt", false, Encoding.ASCII));
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("file.txt", false, Encoding.UTF8));
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("file.txt", false, Encoding.UTF7));
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("file.txt", false, Encoding.UTF32));
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("file.txt", false, Encoding.Unicode));
```

And when saving the file, too (StreamWriter instead). I've also tried a few weird encoding stuff I've found here and some experimentations of my own:

```
new ASCIIEncoding().GetString(Encoding.Convert(Encoding.UTF8, Encoding.Default, byteArray))
"operaci?n"

new ASCIIEncoding().GetString(Encoding.Convert(Encoding.UTF8, Encoding.Unicode, byteArray))

"F\0o\0p\0e\0r\0a\0c\0i\0??n\0"

new ASCIIEncoding().GetString(Encoding.Convert(Encoding.UTF8, Encoding.UTF32, byteArray))
"F\0\0\0o\0\0\0p\0\0\0e\0\0\0r\0\0\0a\0\0\0c\0\0\0i\0\0\0??\0\0n\0\0\0"

new ASCIIEncoding().GetString(Encoding.Convert(Encoding.UTF8, Encoding.UTF7, byteArray))
"operaci+//0-n"

new ASCIIEncoding().GetString(Encoding.Convert(Encoding.UTF8, Encoding.ASCII, byteArray))
"operaci?n"

new ASCIIEncoding().GetString(Encoding.Convert(Encoding.UTF8, Encoding.BigEndianUnicode, byteArray))
"\0F\0o\0p\0e\0r\0a\0c\0i??\0n\0"

new ASCIIEncoding().GetString(Encoding.Convert(Encoding.UTF8, Encoding.GetEncoding(65001), byteArray))
"operaci???n"

new ASCIIEncoding().GetString(Encoding.Convert(Encoding.ASCII, Encoding.GetEncoding(65001), byteArray))
"operaci???n"

Encoding.GetEncoding(65001).GetString(Encoding.Convert(Encoding.UTF8, Encoding.GetEncoding(65001), byteArray))
"operaci�n"

Encoding.GetEncoding(65001).GetString(Encoding.Convert(Encoding.UTF8, Encoding.ASCII, byteArray))
"operaci?n"
```

I've also tried different functions:

```
public static string utf2ascii(string text)        
{
    ASCIIEncoding ascii = new ASCIIEncoding();
    byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(text);
    byte[] asciiArray = Encoding.Convert(Encoding.UTF8, Encoding.ASCII, byteArray);
    return ascii.GetString(asciiArray);
}
```

And

```
public static string utf2ascii(string text)        
{
    System.Text.Encoding utf8 = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
    Byte[] encodedBytes = utf8.GetBytes(text);
    Byte[] convertedBytes = Encoding.Convert(Encoding.UTF8, Encoding.ASCII, encodedBytes);
    System.Text.Encoding ascii = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII;
    return ascii.GetString(convertedBytes);*/
}
```

Without avail. As you can see, nothing works. I've also looked up this app: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17201/Detect-Encoding-for-In-and-Outgoing-Text and the demo program with the real string comes up as this:

[image: Encoding test]

Which leaves me to guess that reading and writing UTF-8 should work, but it doesn't :(.

Any ideas are really welcome and appreciated! Thanks in advance :)

---

Okay, solved, thanks all! turns out the file was saved in Windows 1252 by Notepad (for some unknown reason) because files saved with Sublime Text or Notepad++ don't suffer from this issue. Still, thanks all for the help and the heads-up, as you all helped me to clear a lot of doubts and pitfalls I've had with encodings before :)

Lookie!

[image: It works]

For those wanting to see the bytes involved, here's the special character:

Error code: `[7]: 65533 '�'` but in codepage 1252: `[7]: 243 'ó'`

My bad, that's how it shows under Visual Studio. The true bytes (taken from a hex editor using Sublime Text) are here, highlighted in yellow:

[image: hex bytes]

Thanks all! :D

Comment: Please show the *bytes* involved - and tell us how you're observing the text. You shouldn't be doing any conversions between encoding, particularly to/from ASCII given that you're interested in a non-ASCII character.

Comment: My guess is you have the encoding Windows-1252 here or Latin-1, none of those you tried.

Comment: Conveting to ACII is not what you want.  In .NET ACSII is the 7 bit - 128 and does not include ó.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.ascii(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: "For those wanting to see the bytes involved, here's the special character: Error code: [7]: 65533 '�' but in codepage 1252: [7]: 243 'ó'" Those are not bytes. The (single) byte involved is 243 and it doesn't mean anything per se without specifying a correct encoding.

Comment: True, thanks @KarolS, I thought that was what you wanted to see. I've updated the OP with a hex-editor screenshot :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most likely that is one of the Windows `ANSI` code pages. Try using `Encoding.GetEncoding(1252)` to decode the text.

```
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("file.txt", false, 
    Encoding.GetEncoding(1252)));
```

I suggest 1252 because that is the most plausible `ANSI` code page to use to write Spanish text.

Beyond that, your best bet is to read the file's contents as a byte array. Let us look at that and we might be able to deduce the encoding.

Comment: shouldn't that read `Encoding.GetEncoding("windows-1254");` or does the compiler already know or infer it's windows

Comment: @DJKRAZE `Encoding.GetEncoding(1252)` is Windows-1252

Comment: `+1` thanks David just double checking I haven't looked at any of the Overloaded Methods in a while I usually use the example in my question

Comment: Alright, thanks everyone for their help, and @David Heffernan for his Encoding.GetEncoding() function, I didn't know you could request different codepages that way. Awesome! I added the solution and a bit more detail in the OP. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Use `Encoding.Default` (will use the so-called ANSI codepage of your local machine which will probably be Windows-1252 for a Spanish-language version of Windows) or `Encoding.GetEncoding("Windows-1252")` (which is guaranteed to be Windows-1252 of course).

*Edit*: On newer versions of .NET, you may need to do `Encoding.RegisterProvider(CodePagesEncodingProvider.Instance);` before `Encoding.GetEncoding("Windows-1252")` will work.

Comment: `Encoding.Default` may well be asking for trouble. A locale independent code codepage seems more likely to be the way forward.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Absolutely. Something like `Encoding.Default` should only be used if you want your application to expect a file that is "local" to the system. For example if the user creates the file with Notepad without considering codepages, it is likely that the file will have the "local" codepage. However, if the file is known to always have encoding CP1252, never use `Encoding.Default`.